# How can I pass a variable to a Lua script from Java? (io.lettuce.core)?

Tags: java, redis, lua, parameter-passing, lettuce

I have a Lua script like this that does an *hgetall* command on a remote Redis cluster:

```
String shaFindAccount = syncCommands.scriptLoad("local hgetAllKeys = function(key) \n" +
                                                "local acc = redis.call('HGETALL', key)\n" +
                                                "return acc\n" +
                                                "end\n");
```

I want to pass a variable to the hgetall call. This is what my eval statement, calling the above script, looks like:

```
list = syncCommands.evalsha(shaFindAccount, ScriptOutputType.MULTI, key);
```

Where `key` is a unique identifier (primary key) of `acc`. Right now this function returns an empty list.

How do I pass a Java variable into the above Lua script with `io.lettuce.core`? (There aren't any connection issues, and I can use a similar query with a hard coded `key` value and it works.)

Comment: You can find some example in [this](https://github.com/wg/lettuce/blob/master/src/test/java/com/lambdaworks/redis/ScriptingCommandTest.java) unit test. It seems you should call it in this way: .evalsha(digest, MULTI, new String[0], key)); and you should refer the argument as ARGV[1].

Comment: @m4gic, you should convert your comment into an answer so that the OP can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find some example in [this unit test](https://github.com/wg/lettuce/blob/master/src/test/java/com/lambdaworks/redis/ScriptingCommandTest.java). It seems you should call it in this way:

```
list = syncCommands.evalsha(digest, MULTI, new String[0], key));
```

And you should refer to the argument as ARGV[1].

Comment: For anyone reading, adding a return to the end of the lua script, like 
`return hgetallkeys(KEYS[1])`
enabled me to pass the variable as was suggested by m4gic